# Github action runs - but expected output not visible in repo

Tags: github, github-actions

I recently tried to implement a Github action that should run daily and save a file to folder in the repository.

The jobs of this Github action run without errors but neither the folder nor the file show up in my repository.

You find the yml file here:

https://github.com/analphabit/github_actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/save_rki_impfmonitoring_excel.yml

```
name: Save RKI-Excel file Impfmonitoring

on: [push] 
  #schedule:
  #  - cron: '0 0 * * *'

jobs:
  save-excel:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Create Directory
      run: |
        mkdir -p data
    - name: Download Excel File
      run: |
        python -c "from urllib.request import urlretrieve; urlretrieve('https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Daten/Impfquotenmonitoring.xlsx?__blob=publicationFile', 'data/data.xlsx')"
    - name: Save Excel File
      run: |
        mv data/data.xlsx data/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")-data.xlsx
```

The idea is that it downloads the xlsx file everyday and stores it with a timestamp in the filename in a directory called "data" situated in the repo "github_actions".

The action runs without errors but directory and files don't show up there.

https://github.com/analphabit/github_actions/actions/runs/3700392300

What am I missing here?

Thank you
Bartleby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just creates a file inside the virtual machine. You need to commit and push the new changes also. For example, by using the [Git Auto Commit](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/git-auto-commit) Action:

```
name: Save RKI-Excel file Impfmonitoring

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * *'

jobs:
  save-excel:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Create Directory
        run: |
          mkdir -p data
      - name: Download Excel File
        run: |
          python -c "from urllib.request import urlretrieve; urlretrieve('https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Daten/Impfquotenmonitoring.xlsx?__blob=publicationFile', 'data/data.xlsx')"
      - name: Save Excel File
        run: |
          mv data/data.xlsx data/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")-data.xlsx

      - uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
        with:
          branch: main
          file_pattern: '*.xlsx'
```

To read more about GH Actions runners, visit the [Runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions#runners) section.

Comment: Thank you very much! I added your example code and now it runs.

I will also check the link to the documentation. Completely missed that commit part for actions before.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to `git add`, `git commit` and `git push`:

This is what I do in my workflows in a `pwsh` step:

```
& git config --local user.email "jesse.houwing@gmail.com"
& git config --local user.name "Jesse Houwing"
& git add .
& git diff HEAD --exit-code | Out-Null
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
{    
    & git commit -m "Regenerating renovate-data.json"
    & git push
}
```

Comment: There might be an action you can use from the marketplace too...

Comment: Thank you! It worked with the marketplace action https://github.com/marketplace/actions/git-auto-commit recommend in the second answer.

Would I add your code just at the start of my yml file?

Comment: End! The workflow executes these commands the same way you would yourself when making changes.kit starts with a clone, checks out the changes, runs your commands and then... At the end... You commit the changes and push them back into the repo.

Comment: Yeah, of course, at the end! Thank's again for clarifying.

Comment: The Github action is working now with this code added to my yml file:

`
    - name: Configure git user
      run: |
        git config --local user.email "user@mail.com"
        git config --local user.name "username"
    - name: Add changes to git
      run: |
        git add .
    - name: Commit changes
      run: |
        git commit -m "Save Excel file for $(date +"%Y-%m-%d")"
        
    - name: Push changes
      run: |
        git push
`